# Synchronising brush backgrounds of two controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Example:
There are two controls: one is 600 "pixels" wide, the other is 200 "pixels" wide and displayed directly below the first one, right aligned with it.  The background of the first control is a `LinearGradientBrush` defined in some resource dictionary.

Goal:
I want te second control to have its background synchronised with the first one in such a way that the second control looks like an extension of the first control.

Problem:
Simple background binding is not an option because the second control's background would stretch the `LinearGradientBrush` over 200 "pixels" while the first control stretches it over 600 "pixels".
Yes, I can define a new brush manually so that the second control matches the first one, but if I change anything (control size, brush), I will have to update the second brush manually again.  I want the backgrounds to be synchronised automatically.

Is there a good solution for `LinearGradientBrush`?
Is there a universal solution for all types of brushes?

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for you. 1 large control containing the two as described. And another control filling the empty space not covered by your two. Have the large containing control with your designed background with transparent backgrounds on your two controls. The last fill control would use the bind the the parent control of all of these. Hope that makes sense. ;)

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a good solution for simple scenarios, but when the the second control (or both of them) is temporarily displayed on top of lots of other controls, it will practically be impossible to implement it.  Things get even more complicated when the window with the first control is defined in another assembly and I want to add the second control matching the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If the ratio between the controls is constant, you can make the background "stretch across" the controls by adjusting the offset, like this:

```
<Grid Width="700" Height="300">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Horizontal gradient -->
    <Grid Width="600" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Red" />
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Width="200" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="-2" />
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Vertical gradient -->
    <Grid Width="600" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Blue" />
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="2" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Width="200" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="-1" />
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is practically defining the brush manually, it will not work if any of controls change its size or the original brush (defined somewhere else, possibly in another assembly) changes.

Comment: This should work if the ratio between the controls is constant as I mentioned, if not I guess you can use a converter to calculate what the offset should be using the height/width of the controls as parameters. This way you should also be able to use the same brush on both controls and set the offsets so it looks like it's one brush stretching over both controls.